ERROR: Chain configuration not found in ink getting-started in cargo contract upload
I was trying the tutorial at
https://use.ink/getting-started/deploy-your-contract#using-cargo-contract
I have substrate node running in another terminal, I already had built the contract and have foobar.contract file in the filesystem. But when I run cargo contract upload --suri '//Alice' I get the below error:
➜ cargo contract upload --suri '//Alice'
ERROR: Chain configuration not found, Allowed configurations:
$crate :: cmd :: config :: Polkadot,
$crate :: cmd :: config :: Substrate,
$crate :: cmd :: config :: Ecdsachain

The command returns instantly, with the error message. It seems to be looking for a configuration that does not exists!? The version of cargo-contract and other versions too:
➜  cargo contract --version
cargo-contract-contract 4.1.1-unknown-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
➜  
➜  cargo --version
cargo 1.83.0-nightly (c1fa840a8 2024-08-29)
➜ rustc --version
rustc 1.83.0-nightly (bd53aa3bf 2024-09-02)
➜

--- update ---
I did a PR fixing this in the source code: https://github.com/use-ink/cargo-contract/pull/1743
I am not sure if it is the right solution, but ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Try using Pop CLI: https://learn.onpop.io/v/contracts/guides/deploying-your-contract-locally
